# what is means and how use nodes_main.txt in litecoin source?

Tags: fork, bitcoin, blockchain

`nodes_main.txt`

> 5.196.77.193:9333
>   31.214.157.83:9333
>   37.157.183.16:9333
>   45.55.176.26:9333
>   46.101.6.204:9333
>   46.105.55.208:9333
>   47.189.129.218:9333
>   62.210.206.140:9333
>   62.210.254.201:9333
>   63.141.224.98:9333
>   66.178.182.35:9333
>   68.60.159.136:9333
>   70.77.123.81:9333
>   71.88.54.22:9333
>   71.120.188.82:9333
>   73.40.6.11:9333
>   77.77.46.250:9333
>   80.77.37.36:9333
>   80.108.143.19:9333
>   80.241.212.207:9333
>   81.27.96.92:9333
>   81.138.88.100:9333
>   82.118.242.3:9333
>   82.192.64.136:9333
>   85.21.144.226:9333
>   85.234.150.199:9333
>   88.198.230.142:9333
>   89.69.140.68:9333
>   89.152.237.246:9333
>   91.109.112.90:9333
>   91.109.112.94:9333
>   91.152.122.132:9333
>   91.240.141.175:9333
>   93.190.140.198:9333
>   97.85.42.188:9333
>   104.172.24.79:9333
>   104.243.38.34:9333
>   107.150.45.210:9333
>   107.191.39.237:9333
>   108.56.194.156:9333
>   109.195.179.63:9333
>   134.213.222.108:9333
>   136.243.153.156:9333
>   158.129.212.236:9333
>   162.13.4.69:9333
>   172.245.161.141:9333
>   173.208.194.94:9333
>   173.209.44.34:9333
>   178.217.186.125:9333
>   184.164.147.82:21333
>   185.8.165.150:10333
>   185.47.62.72:9333
>   185.50.213.124:9333
>   185.66.250.44:9333
>   185.87.184.29:9333
>   188.0.182.10:9335
>   188.155.136.21:9333
>   192.3.165.30:9333
>   198.15.127.242:10333
>   217.23.14.155:9333
>   217.28.96.180:9333

The above is node data of `IPv4`.

These are converted to `16 bits IPv6` and placed in `chainparamsseeds.h`
what these are means and how use?

also, `chainparams.cpp`

```
vSeeds.push_back(CDNSSeedData("loshan.co.uk", "seed-a.litecoin.loshan.co.uk", true));
vSeeds.push_back(CDNSSeedData("thrasher.io", "dnsseed.thrasher.io", true));
vSeeds.push_back(CDNSSeedData("litecointools.com", "dnsseed.litecointools.com"));
vSeeds.push_back(CDNSSeedData("litecoinpool.org", "dnsseed.litecoinpool.org"));
vSeeds.push_back(CDNSSeedData("koin-project.com", "dnsseed.koin-project.com"));
```

What's the difference with these above?

Comment: Haven't got the answer ???

Comment: sadly... I did not get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domains listed in `chainparams.cpp` are for DNS seeders. DNS seeders are not nodes themselves, but rather are DNS servers that serve the IP addresses of nodes that are available to be connected to. These can be connected to for both a normal connection and just one to retrieve more IP addresses of nodes.

The IP addresses listed in `chainparamseeds.h` are the IP addresses of nodes that can be connected to. This connection can be an actual connection or just one which retrieves more IP addresses of nodes that can be connected to.

To setup a seed node, you just need to run a normal node for your altcoin and add its IP address to `chainparamseeds.h`. There should be a script that actually constructs this for you in `contrib/seeds`.